# Reduce array with lodash and specific condition

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'd like to reduce my array of objects using `lodash`.

My object:

```
[
    {date: '01/01/2016', price: 5},
    {date: '01/01/2016', price: 10},
    {date: '01/02/2016', price: 500}
]
```

After the reduce:

```
[
    {date: '01/01/2016', price: 15},
    {date: '01/02/2016', price: 500}
]
```

The main goal is to check if there is identical dates and accumulate the price into a simple object...

Answer (score 5):

Using a lodash [chain](https://lodash.com/docs#_):

```
var results = _(data).groupBy('date').map(function(v, k) {
  return { date : k, price : _.sum(v, 'price') };
}).value();
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution in plain javascript with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
var data = [{ date: '01/01/2016', price: 5 }, { date: '01/01/2016', price: 10 }, { date: '01/02/2016', price: 500 }],
    reduced = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        !r.some(function (b) {
            if (a.date === b.date) {
                b.price += a.price;
                return true;
            }
        }) && r.push({date:a.date, price:a.price});            
        return r;
    }, []);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(reduced, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```